# how to implement hook_theme drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Im new to drupal,I need to render a form so i have to implement hook theme, my confusion is Under which directory I should create hook theme file in drupal 8?

```
// my_module.module

function custom_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
      return array(
         'customize_form' => array(
         'variables' => array(
         'Custom_Form' => NULL
        ),
       'render element' => 'form'
      ),
    );
}
```

where I have to put above file in drupal 8??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: follow the steps on how to create a module, and place the code in module_name.module file https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/naming-and-placing-your-drupal-8-module

Comment: Just to be clear, you do not **have to** implement hook_theme to render a form, it will use the default.

Comment: @2pha ok where I have to put my_module.module file,I mean under which folder??

Comment: It is all outlined in the link in the first comment. It may not be obvious, but the different parts of the tutorial are linked to on the right hand side of the page.

Answer (score 2):

In your .module file

```
File location - module/custom/MODULENAME/MODULENAME.module
    /**
     * @file
     * Twig template for render content
     */
    function MODULENAME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
      return [
        'theme_name_template' => [
          'variables' => ['flag' => NULL],
        ],
      ];
    }
    To Use theme function use below code 
    return ['#theme' => 'theme_name_template', '#flag' => 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right you want the folder to place your module, right? You have to put your module in a folder under
**/modules/custom/your_module_folder** or **/sites/all/modules/your_module_folder**